# MVC Kendo ListView Edit and Delete Button disappearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listview, kendo-ui

My edit-buttons disappear by clicking the edit button.
Normally they should turn into save and cancel buttons automatically as far as in understood.
By clicking the edit button the whole content inside my div(idCustomerTemplate) is replaced by an editor template.

Telerik Website says:
Note: Click events for elements with class name k-update-button and k-cancel-button will be automatically handled and treated by Kendo ListView as save and cancel actions. The editor template should be wrapped in a HTML container, same as the item template.

Anyone has a hint for me ?

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="idCustomerTemplate">
       <div class="clsCustomerListView">
          <dl>
             <dt>Firmenname</dt>
             <dd>#=CompanyName#</dd>
             <dt>Adresse</dt>
             <dd>#=Adress#</dd>
             <dt>Postleitzahl</dt>
             <dd>#=ZipCode#</dd>
             <dt>Ort</dt>
             <dd>#=Location#</dd>
             <dt>Land</dt>
             <dd>#=Country#</dd>
          </dl>
          <div class="edit-buttons">
             <a class="k-button k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>
             <a class="k-button k-delete-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>
          </div>
       </div>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline) might help you for inline editing of kendo grid in asp.net mvc.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Discontinued).Width(100);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(172);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ProductID))
        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Grid"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "Grid"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Grid"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
    )
)
```